# Error catching in JavaScript does not catch error properly

Tags: javascript, error-handling, assets, p5.js

I am working on a game in javascript which utilizes the p5.js library. I am trying to load my own font, in which I am using a .ttf file, but sometimes, p5.js doesn't properly load the font. in cases like this, I am trying to use the try and catch method to check if this happens, and if it does, to switch my font to a default built-in font that always works (not a .ttf, just built-in). Here is my code pertaining to the issue:

```
function preload() {

  try {

    font = loadFont("assets/BebasNeue-Regular.ttf"); // Font from Google Fonts - https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Bebas+Neue#standard-styles

  } catch (error) {

    console.error("ERROR: " + error)
    console.log("Font was unable to load, using default font.");
    font = "Helvetica";

  }

  console.log("Assets preloaded...");

}
```

However, whenever I try to run my code, not only does my canvas not load anything, but the error still appears in the console. My console.log statement, however, is not there. Here is what it says:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: blob:null/a07d873c-2d5e-4653-92f4-02fd085cc6e4
p5.js:48337 
 p5.js says: It looks like there was a problem loading your font. Try checking if the file path (assets/BebasNeue-Regular.ttf) is correct, hosting the file online, or running a local server. (More info at https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Local-server)
p5.js:80410 Font could not be loaded assets/BebasNeue-Regular.ttf
(anonymous) @ p5.js:80410
assets/BebasNeue-Regular.ttf:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

Even though my asset is in my folder, when I try to run the program, it does not work. Does anyone know how to fix/change my error-catching statement?

EDIT: I tried a different way of error catching, which is provided by p5 in the [loadFont() procedure](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadFont). Here is what my new code is:

```
function preload() {

  font = loadFont("assets/BebasNeue-Regular.ttf", setup, fontError); // Font from Google Fonts - https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Bebas+Neue#standard-styles

  console.log("Assets preloaded...");

}

function fontError() { console.log("Font was unable to load, using default font."); font = "Helvetica"; }

function setup() {

  // Sets up the game, irrelevant to error.
  
}
```

Here is a link to my code download is it helps: https://www.mediafire.com/file/k4nm445dkxhv0i8/game.zip/file

Comment: Looking at the error message, my assumption is that `loadFont` is handling the error internally and not throwing an exception. Try putting in the absolute path to the ttf font and see if that works. Just speculating it's likely your javascript file is being run from a different directory than you think it is, so the relative path is off.

Comment: Is `loadFont` a promise?

Comment: I think loadFont is a promise, but I'm not 100% sure (sorry, I'm still new to this concept). If it helps, here is p5's explanation of the statement: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadFont

Comment: By putting in the absolute path, do you mean starting from "C://Users..." etc? If so, would it not be different if I ran the program on another device?

Comment: `loadFont` accepts two more arguments, a success and an error callback. You need to use the second one to catch errors. It's documented right there in the documentation link you provided.

Comment: Oh no, I never noticed this. Thank you for pointing this out for me!

Edit: I just tried this, but the issue remains. The asset is not being loaded, and the callback isn't being called. Is it perhaps an error in my code?

Comment: The `callback` parameter is not being called because the load fails. This means the `onError` callback (the third parameter) _is_ being called, but you did not provide one.

Comment: does my fontError() function not work as that? I have redeclared the "font" variable to "Helvetica" in it, which should work.

Comment: How are you running your code? In a webbrowser?

Comment: Yes, in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadFont) states:

> Outside of `preload()`, you may supply a callback function to handle the
> object:

You should refactor your code like this:

```
let font;

function preload() {
  loadFont("assets/BebasNeue-Regular.ttf", result => {
    console.log("Assets preloaded...");
    font = result;
  }, error => {
    console.error("ERROR: " + error)
    console.log("Font was unable to load, using default font.");
    font = "Helvetica";
  });
}

function setup() {
  // use the font
}
```

Comment: I tried this, the error still remains. is it perhaps an error with the loadFont() procedure, or maybe in my code?